# How write html code in string to create a code snippet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Modal show={props.show} onHide={() => props.close()} size="lg" centered aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                some random text................
                        
                You include the script with the following code:
                  <script src='script.js'></script>

                        
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => props.close()}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary">
                    Download
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
```

In the above code I want the script tag line in `Modal.Body` to be displayed as text but instead the code is being executed. I tried enclosing the script tag in `span` but its still doesn't work, same is happening with `<input>` and `<canvas>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the **Less than sign** (`<`) with `&lt;` and similarly replace the **Greater than
sign** (`>`) with `&gt;`.

So your code will become:

```html
&lt;script src='script.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```